# Need information from DB

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP coding and now a friend helped me alot, I'm ashamed to ask him to fix my code.
I've created a link where I get category.php?nameID=ID, but when I go to category.php I want to see on this page all category's like this:
1. category
2. category1
3. category2
But all clickable so when I click on category I go to mysite.com/category.php?nameID=1 and only see the content of category 1, 
For example I want this code:

```
echo "<b>" . $row['name'] . "</b> added on: " . $row['date'] . ", about this game <b>"
```

also on category.php but with all category's

I got this code now:

```
<html>
<?php
 include 'config.php';

  if(isset($_GET['p'])){ 
   $p = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']); 
   $mysql = (" SELECT * FROM category WHERE id ='".$p."'"); 
   $result = mysql_query($mysql); 
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   echo "<b>" . $row['name'] . "</b> added on: " . $row['date'] . ", about this game <b>" . $row['description'] . "</b>";

   }else{

   echo 'Nothing to find here';
  }
?>
</html>
```

thank you very much, I hope you can help me!

Comment: Aside: If it's an integer `$mysql = (" SELECT * FROM category WHERE id =".(int)$_GET['p']);` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some fundamental tags like `<head>` and `<body>`. I think you're asking this:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

// create a where clause
if (isset($_GET['p'])) $where="id=".(int)$_GET['p'];
else $where=1;

// select all or specific using the where clause
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE ".$where;
$result = mysql_query($mysql);

// if there are rows returned
if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
    // iterate
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<li><a href=\"category.php?p=".$row['id']."\"><b>" . $row['name'] . "</b></a> added on: " . $row['date'] . ", about this game <b>" . $row['description'] . "</b>";
    }
}else{
    echo 'Nothing to find here';
}
?>
```

P.S. Please don't use mysql, it's deprecated; use [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo). When writing a SELECT statement, make sure there are no spaces before SELECT - I've found that SQL cache only caches if the string starts with S.

Comment: Thank you helped alot, just only needed to change id to nameID and " . $row . " to $data. Is it posible to get on my page category.php?p=4 for example, just only the $data['description'] ? thank you very much

Comment: How can using the column `nameID` be correct when the lookup, given in the question, uses `id`? `WHERE id=1`